# How to return all columns of tableA and one column of joined table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How do I express this in LinqToEntities?

```
 Select a.*, b.Name as ParentName from items a 
    inner join items b on a.ParentId = b.id
    where a.Id = 1
```

Item is a fairly large table, and I only want to retrieve a single column and include it in the result set. This is as close as I can get:

```
 var query = from a in this.DbContext.Items
        join b in this.DbContext.Items
        on a.ParentId equals b.Id
        select a;
```

I don't see how to return ParentName as part of the Item

In the Entity Class, I added:

```
[NotMapped]
public string FolderName{ get; set; }
```

But I don't see how to populate this.

I then need to send this back to the controller, serialize it to Json and send it down to the client (browser) so I don't think I can use an anonymous type or a valuetuple here.

Comment: LINQ To SQL != Entity Framework != Entity Framework Core. Please clarify which framework you are using. What's used in EF and EF Core is LINQ To Entities, by the way.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, thank you, didn't realize that.  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should project into a new DTO class that is designed to hold the correct properties. For example:

The class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }
    public string AnotherValue { get; set; }
    //etc
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
}
```

The query:

```
var query = from a in this.DbContext.Items
    join b in this.DbContext.Items
    on a.ParentId equals b.Id
    select new Foo
    {
        SomeValue = a.SomeValue,
        AnotherValue = a.AnotherValue,
        //etc
        ParentName = b.Name

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't shoehorn `b`'s columns into `a`, but you can combine the two in an object of a named type you define for combining the two:

```
class ItemAndParent {
    Item A { get; set; }
    string ParentName { get; set; }
}

var query = from a in this.DbContext.Items
    join b in this.DbContext.Items
    on a.ParentId equals b.Id
    select new ItemAndParent {
        A = a,
        ParentName = b.Name
    };
```

Comment: @But I don't think I can return an anonymous type back to the controller, then serialize it to Json and send it to the client. I realize now I should have included that fact in the question.

Comment: @Greg0 Then you should make a named type that you could return back to the controller, and use it in `select`. Please see the edit.